# How to rollback 1 file, make some changes, and push commit into the newest?

Tags: svn

I noticed that I made a lot of error in one of my app.css file.
I am currently on r20.

I have used a rollback command:
svn up -r 10 src/main/webapp/css/app.css

I added a lot of code in and fixes the problem.
How do I push this commit into r21?
I have try committing by doing svn commit but getting error : "src/main/webapp/css/app.css' is out of date"

I want to push this file

Answer (score 0):

You have only checked out a previous version (r10) when you did:

```
svn up -r 10 src/main/webapp/css/app.css
```

You can't simply commit in this state, as HEAD is at r20. **If all other commits (r11 through r20) are faulty and can be discarded**, simply move/rename your `src/main/webapp/css/app.css` to e.g. `src/main/webapp/css/app.css.fixed`, then do an...

```
svn up
```

...to get the working copy up-to-date, rename `src/main/webapp/css/app.css.fixed` back to `src/main/webapp/css/app.css` (overwriting the r20 version), and then commit that file.

**If the other commits (r11 through r20) can't be discarded**, you'll have to do a manual merge between `src/main/webapp/css/app.css.fixed` and `src/main/webapp/css/app.css` (r20) with your diffing/merging tool of choice and finally commit the resulting file.